# How to get overlapping edges using igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to create a network graph with overlapping edges.

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph( c(1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,3, 2,3, 3,5), n=5, directed=FALSE )
V(g) #Vertex sequence
E(g) #Edge sequence
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, vertex.label=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

[image: Result]

This results in 8 non-overlapping edges between 'a' and 'b'. What can I do to replace these non-overlapping lines with a thicker line (proportional to 8 times a single line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `curved` to `FALSE`, and `width` to the number of multiple edges using `count.multiple`, see the details in the manual: http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html

```
E(g)$curved <- FALSE
E(g)$width <- count.multiple(g)
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, vertex.label=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

[image: graph plot]

Comment: Thanks! The width part was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Used edge.curved=FALSE and got the result.